# mapping to open existing file in a split window, creates a blank last line, then enters insert mode

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to combine several commands into a single mapping - (i) open a split window with a height of 15 lines, (ii) open an existing file in that window, (iii) move to the last line and char of that file, (iv) create a new blank line thereafter, (v) and enter insert mode.

This achieves (i) and (ii):

```
nnoremap <leader>n :15sp +$ $HOME/_notes/n0w<cr>
```

I've tried to extend upon it with:

```
nnoremap <leader>n :15sp +$A $HOME/path/to/file<cr>
nnoremap <leader>n :15sp +$ +A $HOME/path/to/file<cr>
nnoremap <leader>n :15sp +A +$  $HOME/path/to/file<cr>
nnoremap <leader>n :15sp +GA  $HOME/path/to/file<cr>
```

which has given the respective results:

```
E464: ambiguous use of user-defined command +$A
+A $/HOME/path/to/file [NEW DIRECTORY]
+S $/HOME/path/to/file [NEW DIRECTORY]
E492: not an editor command
```

I've also tried similar variations with `+startinsert` and `+normal` but not getting the desired result.

Would greatly appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to embed commands in the split. You can use multiple commands in a single mapping.

```
nnoremap <leader>n :15sp $HOME/_notes/n0w<cr>Go
```

After the split command is submitted with `<cr>`, this being `nmap` we can just specify Normal mode commands. Specifically, `G` for step (iii) (go to end of file) and `o` for steps (iv) and (v) (add a new line and enter Insert mode).

That's it.

(An assist to @JürgenKrämer for a shorter command and subsequent revelation that I have config/plugin issues.)

Comment: Having said that about norm, `Go` is basically `$put =''`, right?

Comment: Why use `exe`, `norm` and `startinsert` at all? `nnoremap <leader>n :15sp $HOME/_notes/n0w<cr>Go` works just as well.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer Hmmm. Because that doesn't leave me in Insert mode. Maybe somethings wack here. Since I had to use startInsert I just  kept it verbose but if I'm just bugged and don't need it then I agree that what you propose is much better. Looking into it. Thanks.

Comment: Just disabled all plugins and don't need startInsert. Wth?! I'm updating my answer b4 anything else. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you.  @BLayer answer has the brevity I had hoped for. Changed the ending `Go` for '<cr>GA<cr>` ,as the former moved the cursor one place in from the start of the line.

Comment: @user2962912 No problem. You sure you didn't have any rogue whitespace in there? My cursor is fully left (though I'm not sure I should trust my config at this point..lol).

Comment: It would be nice to explain why `+$A`, `+$ +A`, `+A +$` and `+GA` don't work, which boil down to the fact that `A` and `G` are normal mode commands. Using `:15sp +normal!\ Go $HOME/_notes/n0w` would have worked to append a new line, and `:15sp +exe\ 'norm!\ Go'\|startinsert $HOME/_notes/n0w` does it all including switching to insert mode. While it looks ugly, it's actually *possible* to do all that from a single `+` in a split command itself.